# How do I handle file names with spaces?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, error-handling, spaces

I am using this code below to copy a file selected in the file browser and copying it to the temp directory with a different name. But when I select a file with spaces in it, the program throws an error saying it cannot find the specified fine path. I have tried using escape methods but they do not work either. Are there any other ways to handle file names with spaces?

Code starts here:

```
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    [openPanel close];

    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        myString = [self randomStringWithLength:7];
        NSString *filePath = [[[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0] absoluteString];

        NSLog(@"%@", filePath);

        NSString *strTemp = [self extractString:filePath toLookFor:@"//" skipForwardX:2 toStopBefore:@".png"];
        NSLog(@"%@",strTemp);
        NSString *realThing = [strTemp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@"\\ "];
        //strTemp = [strTemp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", realThing);

        NSString* fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/tmp/%@.png", myString];
        NSLog(fullPath);


        NSError *error = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:realThing toPath:fullPath error:&error];
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error!!!");
            NSLog(@" error => %@ ",error);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Saved to temp directory");
        }
```

Anyone have experience with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conversion of the URL to a path is much too complicated and error-prone.
Just use the `path` method:

```
NSString *filePath = [[[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0] path];
```

Alternatively, use `copyItemAtURL:...` instead of `copyItemAtPath:...`.

You also should check the *return value* of `copyItemAtPath:...` as the indicator
of a failure:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:fullPath error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@" error => %@ ",error);
}
```

Compare [Handling Error Objects Returned From Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1):

> **Important:** Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the
>   method. Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in
>   the Cocoa error domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the
>   method indicates failure by directly returning nil or NO, you should
>   always check that the return value is nil or NO before attempting to
>   do anything with the NSError object.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to convert URLs to file paths by hand. Use fileSystemRepresentation instead.

Comment: `fileSystemRepresentation` is an `NSString` method and returns a C string that can be used with "low-level" functions like `open()` or `rename()`.